# Eclipse : have a custom color/font for a specific annotation

Tags: java, eclipse, annotations

like @Deprecated, I would like to create an annotation that can have a specific color/font rendered in my Eclipse editor (currently Oxygen).
Is it possible ?

Comment: yes it is possible...

Comment: Ok... how please ?

Comment: I think this is not possible, but @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ says it is. I'am really curious to see how you can do this.

Comment: Saying it is possible without giving any hint... seems like trolling to me